# Magento module - database not initialized?

Tags: database, magento, module

So I've installed an extension in my Magento Enterprise.

I've been able to configure new options in the admin interface after installing the module.

However in the frontend it complains "table not found". Checking the database that is indeed true. Seems the mysql4-*.php scripts have not been run or failed.

Is there a log or something I can look at to see what goes wrong? From what I've read (difficult to find documentation on this) the modules db should've been initialized on the first request after it was installed and activated.

Any other suggestions to what I can check to find out why it's not initialized properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to check the core_resource table. If there's a row for your module, then zap it. This will retrigger the [setup resource](http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources) process.

Comment: Aha. Well seems it (kreditor_setup) is not in there. The db init of the module is in ./app/code/local/Kreditor/Kreditor/sql/kreditor_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php. That means the modules db config has not been triggered at all? Thanks for your link.

Comment: Aaaaahhhh!!! Caching affects resource setup. Can't believe I didn't remember to flush the cache before asking silly questions. Again.
Oh well! A big bunch of thanks, Alan. Your article tipped me of with "flush the cache". :) sorry to waste your time!

Comment: Heh, yeah, flushing the cache is like zapping the pram, except it actually works!